# Luhn algorithm for odd and even card numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

I am confused about when to multiply a number and when to add it. Is it inclusively every second number or is it when the number is odd?

For example a 16-digit card (starting from the last digit) 4 would be added and 3 would be multiplied.

1234 5678 9101 1234

But if it is a 15-digit card number would the same rule apply or do I always multiply odd numbers in this case (again starting from the last number) 4 would be multiplied and 3 would be added?

1234 5678 9101 134

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm seems to be quite clear: “With the payload, start from the **rightmost digit**. Moving left, double the value of every second digit (including the rightmost digit).”

Comment: Odd *from the right*.  In 1234567891011234 it is **1**2**3**4**5**6**7**8**9**1**0**1**1**2**3**4.  In 12345678910134 it is **1**2**3**4**5**6**7**8**9**1**0**1**1**3**4**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For odd placed digits going back from the check digit, you have the following mapping:

0. 0
1. 2
2. 4
3. 6
4. 8
5. 1
6. 3
7. 5
8. 7
9. 9

Then add all digits, including the check digit it should form a multiple of ten

So the first card number maps to:
2+2+6+4+1+6+5+8+9+0+2+2+6+4= 57 and isn't valid.

The second card number maps to:
1+4+3+8+5+3+7+7+9+0+1+2+3+4= 57 and isn't valid either. Credit cards may have 4 check digits calculated separately. Hence part of why you don't give the last 4 of your card given a certain length. The start of some luhnable card numbers are things like card supplying bank and specific branch of bank which are going to be fairly easy to fill in, in theory.